# Shift one rows in a 2D Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, row, shift

I am trying to make a game called Numbrosia for my computer science lab. It has to be a 5x5 board but when I try to shift the values within the rows either to the right or left some of my columns disappears.

The array's values are

```
 1 -2  1  0  0
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

But I am getting

```
0 0 1 -2 
0 2 4 0 
0 -1 1 -4 
0 -1 -1 1 
0 -1 1 -3
```

I will put my piece of code of the method that shifts it to the right

```
public public static void RowRight(int i, int[][] array){
   for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
       int temp = array[i][array.length-1];
       for(int col = array.length-2; col > 0; col--){
           array [row][col+1] = array[row][col];
           System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
       }
       System.out.println("");
   }
}
```

I await someone's response thank you

----------UPDATE-----------------------------

I've managed to print the 5 columns but a new problem surfaced. Either if I shift the values in the row to the left or to the right, the position next to either the last number(that when shifting left was the first number) or the first number(when shifting right was the last number) has the same exact number as either the first or last.
I'll put the outputs

again the array values are

```
 1 -2  1  0  0
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

and I need to get for example the first row to move to the left, so it should print

```
-2  1  0  0  1
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

but I am getting this

```
-2  1  0  1  1
-1  0  4  2  0
 0 -4  1 -1  0
 0  1 -1 -1 -2
 0 -3  1 -1  0
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You usually shift rows right or up, what do you mean shift them left/right?

Comment: @peter.petrov - I think it means shifting values left/right within a single row.

Comment: If you want to shift just one row, you don't need two nested loops. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift row #i to the right/left as follows.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test037 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] x = 
        {
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 },
            { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 }
        };

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));

        shiftRight(0, x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));

        shiftLeft(0, x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));

        shiftLeft(0, x);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(x));
    }

    /**
     * Shifts row #i one position to the right.
     */
    public static void shiftRight(int i, int[][] array) {
        int m = array[i].length;
        int temp = array[i][m-1];
        for (int k=m-1; k>=1; k--){
            array[i][k] = array[i][k-1];
        }
        array[i][0] = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Shifts row #i one position to the left.
     */
    public static void shiftLeft(int i, int[][] array) {
        int m = array[i].length;
        int temp = array[i][0];
        for (int k=0; k<m-1; k++){
            array[i][k] = array[i][k+1];
        }
        array[i][m-1] = temp;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement shift for colum http://paste.ubuntu.com/12901624/ is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with `temp`, so it's value gets lost. You probably want something like this:

```
for(int row = 0; row < array.length; row++){
   int temp = array[i][array.length-1];
   System.out.print(temp + " ");
   for(int col = array.length-2; col >= 0; col--){
       array [row][col+1] = array[row][col];
       System.out.print(array[row][col] + " ");
   }
   array[row][0] = temp;
   System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: sorry that was a mistake of mine, I changed it to have temp in it, still gives me out the same result.

Comment: @user2958626 - I changed the loop termination condition from `col > 0` to `col >= 0`. See if that makes any difference. If not, please edit your to show a specific example (with values and output) showing what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will solve your problem.

```
private static void RowRight(int shiftRow, int[][] array){
    if(array.length != 0 && array[0].length != 0){
        // to check for empty arrays

        int temp = array[shiftRow][array[shiftRow].length - 1];

        for(int col = 1; col < array[shiftRow].length; col++){
            array[shiftRow][col] = array[shiftRow][col - 1]; 
        }

        array[shiftRow][0] = temp;
    }

    traverse(array);
}      

private static void traverse(int a[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```